# Android Studio Lagging Issues

Tags: android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio Hedgehog 2023 to learn Android Mobile app development. But ever since I downloaded it, it has been really laggy on my PC. My PC is 4GB RAM, and a processor speed 1.6GHz. I don't know what to do. I really wanna learn Mobile app development.

If I should open the software now, before the software can be fully ready for use, it would take the next 1hr... Yet upon that, it's still really laggy. Gradle build is updating everytime, and I have never successfully run any single command. I'm always get series of error responses.

I'm learning Mobile app development from a course I bought on Udemy, but I can't apply or replicate what I'm learning there on my PC. Help pls

I tried not opening any other apps, it still didn't work. I kept updating Gradle, and it's always updating forever until my PC battery dies out. It's just super slow. I'm so discouraged...